# Why do stored procedures and functions improve performance?

Tags: performance, stored-procedures, plsql

options are

A. They reduce network round trips.

B. They reduce the number of calls to the database and decrease network traffic by bundling
commands.

C. They reduce the number of calls to the database and decrease network traffic by using the local PL/SQL engine.

D. They allow the application to perform high-speed processing locally.

E. They postpone PL/SQL parsing until run time.

I think the answer should be A and B but i came across answers as B and E
Can u explain me what is the difference between option A and B
and does it postpone parsing till runtime? how?

Comment: 'postpone parsing till runtime'??  That sounds like the opposite of stored procedures!

Comment: @MartinJames: sir that means A and B are correct right?

Answer (score 0):

To me, the correct answer would be D. The biggest advantage of stored procedures is that they're compiled into the database, thus allowing high-speed processing.

**Edit** : with Codo's comment, let me clarify. When I read "locally", I read as "in the database engine".

The number of calls is usually not reduced since you usually make only one request to get/set your datas.

P.S. : I guess you got that question from a test? :)

Comment: It would interpret "locally" as where the application or application server runs. Then option D would be incorrect.

Comment: Heh, I guess I interpret "locally" as "in the database engine" :)

Comment: @Florian Margaine: even I think locally means on the client machine where application resides